# MYSQL: COUNT with GROUP BY, LEFT JOIN and WHERE clause doesn't return zero values

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm sure this has a very simple answer, but I can't seem to find it (not sure what to search on!). A standard count / group by query may look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`t2`.`name`) 
FROM `table_1` `t1` 
    LEFT JOIN `table_2` `t2` ON `t1`.`key_id` = `t2`.`key_id` 
WHERE `t1`.`another_column` = 123
```

and this works as expected, returning 0 if no rows are found. However:

```
SELECT COUNT(`t2`.`name`) 
FROM `table_1` `t1` 
    LEFT JOIN `table_2` `t2` ON `t1`.`key_id` = `t2`.`key_id` 
WHERE `t1`.`another_column` = 123 
GROUP BY `t1`.`any_col`
```

only works if there is at least one row in table_1 and fails miserably returning an empty result set if there are zero rows. I would really like this to return 0! Anyone enlighten me on this? Beer can be provided in exchange if you are in London ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it returns zero rows is that you are grouping on a value in table_1. SInce there are no values in table_1, there are no rows to return. Said another way, if you returned t1.any_col in your query from the GROUP BY like so:

```
SELECT `t1`.`any_col`, COUNT(`t2`.`name`) 
FROM `table_1` `t1` 
    LEFT JOIN `table_2` `t2` ON `t1`.`key_id` = `t2`.`key_id` 
WHERE `t1`.`another_column` = 123 
GROUP BY `t1`.`any_col`
```

What would display for t1.any_col when there were no rows? The only way to achieve what you want is to union your results with another query that checks for no rows in table_1. In this example, I'm using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA view simply to have something against which I can query.

```
SELECT COUNT(`t2`.`name`) 
FROM `table_1` `t1` 
    LEFT JOIN `table_2` `t2` ON `t1`.`key_id` = `t2`.`key_id` 
WHERE `t1`.`another_column` = 123 
GROUP BY `t1`.`any_col` 
UNION ALL
SELECT 0
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
Where Not Exists( Select 1 From `table_1` )
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Why does the first example work nicely then? All that is missing is the WHERE clause, there can still be no rows and this will work just fine...

Comment: @Paul Norman - The first example works because clearly there are rows in the table_1. The third example does not work because apparently there are no rows in table_1 that have a value 123 for `another_column`. If the query without the grouping returns no rows, then it will not return rows with the grouping.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the better solution:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT `t2`.`name`
FROM `table_1` `t1` 
    LEFT JOIN `table_2` `t2` ON `t1`.`key_id` = `t2`.`key_id` 
WHERE `t1`.`another_column` = 123 
GROUP BY `t1`.`any_col`) tmp
```

You just need to wrap `SELECT COUNT(*)` around the query.

The problem is that `COUNT()` changes from meaning "give me a count of the rows in the result set" to an aggregate function meaning "give me a count of the rows for each group that match my criteria" when used with the `GROUP BY` clause. In your case, since there are no rows for the group where another_column = 123, nothing is returned.

If you wrap that in another `SELECT COUNT(*)`, you're again saying, "give me a count of the rows in the result set".

In the first query, `COUNT()` is working with `GROUP BY`. But with no criteria specified, you're getting at least one row returned from table_1. Since there are no corresponding table_2 records, NULL evaluates to 0 for `COUNT()`. Don't use the first query. Though it returns what you're expecting, it's only by chance. For the query to be meaningful, you should specify criteria for t1.another_column in the `WHERE` clause.

The second query works because you're asking for a row count of the result set. Since there are no rows where t1.another_column = 123, there are 0 rows returned, and `COUNT()` evaluates to 0.

Comment: This sadly only tells me how many unique 'groups' there are. So if there is only one distinct `any_col` value in `table_1`, but 5 rows of data where `any_col` = 5 this would return 1, not 5 as required (because the nested SELECT would only return one row).

Comment: @Paul, please refresh your browser. I had fixed this. Notice that COUNT() is only used in the outer query.

Comment: I did make that change myself, but I still think (or rather I have tested) that GROUP BY in the nested query means that only one row will be returned if the only data in the table has a single `any_col` value (i.e. if every row has `any_col` = 5, then only one row will be returned by the nested select - as you would expect - and then it follows that counting this data then only produces 1, not the required 5). 

The solution above works a treat anyway, never thought of that! Thanks for all the help.

It's hard to be clear in this tiny box!